# data frame values are same despite the if condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following code to rename column values of a csv

```
def change_tac_to_label():
    df = pd.read_csv("combined.csv", delimiter=',')
    tacs = df['tac']

    for tac in tacs:
        if float(tac) >= 0.08:
            df['tac'] = "bad"
        else:
            df['tac'] = "good"

    df.to_csv("combined_labeled.csv")
```

but saved csv file have all `tac` column values as `good`. There should be something I am missing here.

**What I tried?**

- I tried setting break point at if condition, condition seems to work.

Comment: you can just use `df['tac'] = np.where(df['tac']>=0.08,'bad','good')` inside your function, no need of looping for this usecase., related : [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: `df['tac'] = "bad"` rewrite the whole series. So your code basically only looks at the last item.

Comment: With your code, you try and create a blank list and keep appending the list with `bad` and `good` according to the conditions and then assign the list to the series. Not tested though

Comment: @anky thanks it works.

Comment: @user158 thanks for confirming, I have closed it to the related link since it worked.

Comment: @QuangHoang `df['tac'] = "bad"` is inside a condition though I could not figure things out even with the debugger.